# Converting Pandas Dataframe to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The following is a Pandas dataframe `df`

```
index_column      value_column
 0                   20
 2                   28
 1                   30
```

It needs to be converted into a numpy array where `index_column` becomes the index of numpy array and `value_column` becomes the corresponding value.

That is `np_arr[0]=20`, `np_arr[1]=30`, `np_arr[2]=28` and so on.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: And what happens when `index_column` isn't a RangeIndex starting from 0? `numpy` array indexing is 0 based, so do you need this to work in general for any arbitrary index arrangement?

Comment: index_column will have 0 to n rows,where n is number of rows in dataframe.But they may not be in ascending order.

Comment: 1) this has been asked before, and 2) please don't follow any of the answers below if you're using 0.24.

Answer (score 2):

```
np_arr = df.value_column.values
```

Comment: @amandasmith: What you have mentioned  is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas internally uses `np.arrays`. The `values` attribute is all you need:

```
df.value_column.values
```

is the `np.array` that you want.

Answer (score 1):

`np_arr = df.value_column.values`

if your column name has special characters like space, use the following:

`np_arr = df['temperature [Celsius]'].values`